# How to grab the indexes of a word that appears more than once in a list of Strings

Tags: java, list, iterator

I have a String[] of words that I want to loop through to get the index of each word when it appears in a target List.

I know that target.indexOf(word) will return the index of the first occurrence of a word, but what if that same word appears more than once in the target list? How would I get the index of each occurrence along with the index of all of the other words and store the indexes in a array for later use?

```java
String[] words = ["this", "test"];
List<String> targetList = Arrays.asList("this", "test", "is", "a", "complicated", "test");
ArrayList<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String word : words) {
    int index = targetList.indexOf(word);
    if (index != -1) {
        indexList.add(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in this example, the word "test" appears twice in the targetList and I'd like to make sure that when looping through the list of words that I don't just always get the first occurrence of "test" would expect the indexList to have the values [0,1,5].

Comment: Mark, sorry for the confusion.. I didn't cut and paste my code so I left a few things out while typing.. It's java and I've made edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wanted to write java. You need to use an array of lists to store each occurrence of words.

```
    String[] words = {"this", "test"};
    String[] targetList = {"this", "test", "is", "a", "complicated", "test"};
    ArrayList<Integer> indexList[] = new ArrayList[words.length];

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
        indexList[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        String current = words[i];
        for(int j=0;j<targetList.length;j++)
        {
            if(words[i].equals(targetList[j]))
            {
                indexList[i].add(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are using a raw type: `new ArrayList[words.length]`. Never use them in new code.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It's an array of ArrayLists (something that can't be done unless the type is raw). In other words, this is a bad quality response and not recommended for use.